# Can F# Quotations be used to create a function applicable to arbitrary F# record types?

Tags: f#, records, quotations

Given an F# record:

```
type R = { X : string ; Y : string }
```

and two objects:

```
let  a = { X = null ; Y = "##" }
let  b = { X = "##" ; Y = null }
```

and a predicate on strings:

```
let (!?) : string -> bool = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
```

and a function:

```
let (-?>) : string -> string -> string = fun x y -> if !? x then y else x
```

is there a way to use F# quotations to define:

```
let (><) : R -> R -> R
```

with behaviour:

```
let c = a >< b // = { X = a.X -?> b.X ; Y = a.Y -?> b.Y }
```

in a way that somehow lets `(><)` work for any arbitrary F# record type, **not just for** `R`.

**Short**: Can quotations be used to generate F# code for a definition of `(><)` on the fly given an arbitrary record type and a complement function `(-?>)` applicable to its fields?

If quotations cannot be used, what can?

Comment: I think you would have to use reflection to do something like that.

Comment: @svick I know. I am just interested in other ways to achieve this if any happens to exist. Especially some that results in F# code generation.

Comment: The only way I see of doing this with .NET is reflection (as @svick has suggested). You could also use F# Macros to automatically create the function for every record you need.

Comment: @RamonSnir - to be clear, F# 2.0 does not have a macro system, I think you are alluding to your own work: http://ramon.org.il/wp/2011/12/text-based-macro-system-for-f/

Comment: @StephenSwensen yes, I am. .NET on its own (including F#) does not support any good solution.

Comment: @RamonSnir - Verily - though T4 templates (C# and VB only) address part of the story (for example, I am currently using them successfully to pre-compile my Entity Framework "views" and to generate statically typed access to my ASP.NET MVC 3 views, Scripts, and Content resources).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use F# quotations to construct a function for every specific record and then compile it using the quotation compiler available in F# PowerPack. However, as mentioned in the comments, it is definitely easier to use F# reflection:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let applyOnFields (recd1:'T) (recd2:'T) f =  
  let flds1 = FSharpValue.GetRecordFields(recd1)  
  let flds2 = FSharpValue.GetRecordFields(recd2)  
  let flds = Array.zip flds1 flds2 |> Array.map f
  FSharpValue.MakeRecord(typeof<'T>, flds)
```

This function takes records, gets their fields dynamically and then applies `f` to the fields. You can use it to imiplement your operator like this (I'm using a function with a readable name instead):

```
type R = { X : string ; Y : string } 
let  a = { X = null ; Y = "##" } 
let  b = { X = "##" ; Y = null } 

let selectNotNull (x:obj, y) =
  if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (unbox x) then y else x

let c = applyOnFields a b selectNotNull
```

The solution using Reflection is quite easy to write, but it might be less efficient. It requires running .NET Reflection each time the function `applyOnFields` is called. You could use quotations to build an AST that represents the function that you could write by hand if you knew the record type. Something like:

```
let applyOnFields (a:R) (b:R) f = { X = f (a.X, b.X); Y = f (a.Y, b.Y) }
```

Generating the function using quotations is more difficult, so I won't post a complete sample, but the following example shows at least a part of it:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

// Get information about fields
let flds = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<R>) |> List.ofSeq

// Generate two variables to represent the arguments
let aVar = Var.Global("a", typeof<R>)
let bVar = Var.Global("b", typeof<R>)

// For all fields, we want to generate 'f (a.Field, b.Field)` expression
let args = flds |> List.map (fun fld ->
  // Create tuple to be used as an argument of 'f'
  let arg = Expr.NewTuple [ Expr.PropertyGet(Expr.Var(aVar), fld)
                            Expr.PropertyGet(Expr.Var(bVar), fld) ]
  // Call the function 'f' (which needs to be passed as an input somehow)
  Expr.App(???, args)

// Create an expression that builds new record
let body = Expr.NewRecord(typeof<R>, args)
```

Once you build the right quotation, you can compile it using F# PowerPack. See for [example this snippet](http://fssnip.net/1W).

Comment: Didn't know F# reflections was so easy. By the way the second part is exactly what I was hoping to hear. I would love to learn quotations to get them to do code gen for me rather than me typing everything on my own. It is encouraging to hear that is possible :)

Comment: @CetinSert One final remark is that you'll need to be a bit careful with generating code using F# quotations. The compilation first translates quotation to a LINQ expression tree and then compiles that. So the compiled code is not going to be as efficient as normal F# code.