# Can I define a record type in terms of another?

Tags: f#

```
type ProcessParametersPair = {Definition:string; Provided:string}
type QueryResult = { DefinitionId:int;DefinitionName:string; ProcessTemplateId:int; StatusName:string; DefinitionArgs:string; BuildArgs:string;
    StatusCode:int option;cleanWorkspaceOption:string; RawProcessParameters:ProcessParametersPair; lastBuild:Tbl_Build}     
type QueryDisplay = { DefinitionId:int;DefinitionName:string; ProcessTemplateId:int; StatusName:Object; DefinitionArgs:string; BuildArgs:string;
    StatusCode:int option;cleanWorkspaceOption:string; RawProcessParameters:Object; lastBuild:Object}
```

do I really have to repeat all fields of the QueryDisplayRecord that match? Can I do something like you can do with record instances? `type QueryDisplay = {QueryResult with lastBuild:Object}`

In this case I'm varying record based on a field type, I'd also love to know if I can do this but on added fields instead of type changed fields.

I am not referring to instances, I'm referring to Record type definitions.

Are either of these possible?

Comment: I'm not completely following this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9249409/57883 but it may be doing something very close to what I'm looking at, but at runtime, instead of compile time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A record type cannot "inherit" from another type. You could put all the common fields in a separate type and reference it:

```
type Common = { A: int; B: int }
type Record1 = { Common: Common; C: int }
type Record2 = { Common: Common; D: int }
```

Or use classes:

```
type Common(a, b) =
    member val A = a
    member val B = b

type Class1(a, b, c) =
    inherit Common(a, b)
    member val C = c

type Class2(a, b, d) =
    inherit Common(a, b)
    member val D = d
```

Comment: sounds like a job for codedom, roslyn,Il Emit, or T4 then